# Save pandas dataframe to s3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, save, boto3

I want to save BIG pandas dataframes to s3 using boto3.

Here is what I am doing now:

```
csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)

s3.put_object(Bucket="bucket-name", Key="file-name", Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

This generates a file with the following permissions:

```
---------- 1 root   root    file-name
```

Hw can I change that in order for the file to be owned by the user that executes the script? i.e user "ubuntu" on a AWS instance

This is what I want:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   file-name
```

Another thing, did anyone try this method with big dataframes? (millions of rows) and does it perform well?
How does it compare to just saving the file locally and using the boto3 copy file method?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 requires multiple-part upload for files above 5GB.

You can implement it with boto3 using a reusable configuration object from TransferConfig class :

```
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig

# default value for parameter multipart_threshold is 8MB (=number of bytes per part)
config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=5GB)

# Perform the transfer
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file('FILE_NAME', 'BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', Config=config)
```

Boto3 documentation here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html

Then there is some limits here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/qfacts.html